# Trouble getting the HTTP response's body on a POST request in Angular

Tags: angular, http, httpresponse

I am making a Registration form on angular 13, but when i receive the response from the API the response I get is always treated as an error and not as the actual response.
When everything on the backend is OK, the API sends a 200 HTTP code plus a message in the body’s response, and when it doesn't, it sends the code 500 and a error message.

I have tried a lot of different methods to print the response's body on the console but it always prints it as an error.

The code is:

```
this.http.post\<any\>('http://localhost:8090/register', formData, {observe:'response'})
.subscribe({
next :(response) => console.log('Response',response),
error: (error) => console.log('El error',error.error),
});
.
```

When looking on the dev tools console after sending a correct form it doesn't show an error with the response and the feedback message can be found on the body, and when I send an incorrect form, the console shows  the response as an error (as it is a 500 HTTP code) and the error message is present on the body too.

This is what I' getting: (I tried submitting the same form 2 times, the first comment is what I am getting, (I want to get the red part) and the next 2 comments are for the second submit)

[image]

Another thing I wanted to know is if is possible to assign a variable inside the subscribe. I have tried to assign error to a global variable but when I try to print it the dev tools console shows an error saying it doesn't have a type.

Thank you so much!!

Edit:
This is what the network console shows,console[image: 1] headers console[image: 2] response[image: 3]

Comment: What does the network console show exactly?

Comment: In the first case it shows the red thing on the screenshot, and on the error case it shows the error message

Comment: The screenshot is not the network tab. Trying to determine if you maybe have a cors error or something else.

Comment: Just edited the post with a screenshot. In the case where everything is OK the response is the cookie embedded on the body, and in case of an error it's just an error message. I just want to get either the error message or the cookie.

Comment: your issue in the first request is that the response from your server isn't valid json. don't know why the second error is happening, but a 500 response means it's an issue on your server.

Comment: Then how I should send the response, I just sent it on the response's body.The 500 response is because i tried submitting the form 2 times, the first time is valid and the second it is not.

Answer (score 1):

First let us use a more conventional pattern:

```
this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8090/register', formData)
  .pipe(catchError(err => console.error('El error', err))
  .subscribe(data => console.log('Response', data));
```

This will give you or the error generated by the server or the data the server sent in the console.

Please share the error or data as a comment in this answer and I will update the answer with more help

Comment: Hello! I tried this and it worked ```this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/registro', formData, {observe:'response', responseType:'text'})
        .subscribe({
          next :(response) => console.log('Response:',response.body),
                              
          error: (error) => console.log('Error:',error.error), 
        });``` Now the problem I have is that i want to save the response's body on a variable but I always get an undefined, I guess It's because the subscribe its an async function.